# Resizing QGraphicsItem does not update Item properties

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

i'm resizing a QGraphicsItem (mItem) as follows:

```
  QRectF itemSize = mItem->boundingRect();

  float scale_width = width / itemSize.width();
  float scale_height = height / itemSize.height();

  QTransform t;
  t.scale(scale_width, scale_height);
  mItem->setTransform(t);
```

visually it does what it should, however, if i get the boundingRect after re-sizing, it has not changed.
I was under the impression that the boundingRect might not change but the scale, but that also stays the same. If the original boundingRect is (0,0,100,100) and the new width id 200 and the new height is 200 i would expect the new boundingRect to be (0,0,200,200).

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation provides a mapping between object-space and the scene's (world) space (or perhaps the parent's object-space) for rendering - it is **not** applied to the object itself.

So setting a scale transformation on an object, will not change it's bounding box, because the object has not been scaled - only the way is it mapped into the scene has.  The [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) explain it better than I can.

`QGraphicsItem` has many `mapTo...` and `mapFrom...` methods that provide what you need.